# How do I stop or remove a jQuery function from a HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am attaching a function like so, which loads with the page or when called again:

```
function scroller(dist){
    $('#gallery').scrollbox({
        direction: 'h', // vertical or horizontal
        distance: dist // the distance between items
    });
}
```

However, when I call this function again, multiple instances of it are working simultaneously. How do I stop or remove this function? I have tried $('#gallery').unbind() as part of the function before calling the scrollbox but this doesn't work.

The scrollbox function can be found [here](https://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox), it is for animating galleries of images.

Comment: That's going to entirely depend on how that "scrollbox" code works. Possibly the best approach would be to avoid calling the function more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unsure whether there is an option to update the scroll distance in the scrollbox plugin. Initially it was not wrapped in a named function, it was just called on page load or resize. I thought that if I wrapped it in a function I would be able to remove it, but so far I have been unable to. Bit of a pain this one.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is add a class to any element that I'd attached the widget to:

```
function scroller(dist){
    $('#gallery:not(.scroll-added)').scrollbox({
        direction: 'h', // vertical or horizontal
        distance: dist // the distance between items
    }).addClass("scroll-added");
}
```

Comment: In addition, i'd suggest looking to the documentation for this plugin for a way to change the options passed in without re-initing the plugin.

Comment: The trouble is that I am adding it again and again to the same element. I need to remove previous instances of the scrollbox code before adding it again, else things get a bit silly with multiple scrolls happening at once.

Comment: @MikeK This answer prevents that very situation.

Comment: @MikeK can you explain **why** you're adding it over and over again to the same element? Most plugins like that are not designed to be removed once they've been applied.

Comment: @Pointy I don't want to, I didn't realise I was until I caught the bug. I'll have to look into updating the value of the scroll but honestly not sure how to go about that at all. I've contacted the plugin author too, so maybe he/she can help.

Comment: @KevinB I see that this prevents me from adding the function to the same element over and over, that is what I have been doing in error, thinking I was replacing the previous function. What I am trying to do now is either remove the previous instance before adding another, or simply updating the value passed in scrollbox().

Comment: It definitely does not seem to have any functionality for resetting or changing options. Looks like you're only option would be to completely remove the html and re-create it from the ground up when you want to re-init it with new options.